# Set current tab on a Gutenberg TabPanel component from outside that component

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm using the [`TabPanel`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/components/tab-panel/) component provided with Gutenberg to display some tabs. I'd like a button within one of the tabs to change the currently visible tab to another one and I can't work out how.

```
var el = wp.element.createElement;
var Component = wp.element.Component;
var Fragment = wp.element.Fragment;
var Button = wp.components.Button;
var TabPanel = wp.components.TabPanel;

function getEditComponent( blockName, blockTitle ) {
    return class extends Component {
        renderTab( tab ) {
            if ( 'show' === tab.name ) {
                return this.getPlotWidget();
            } else if ( 'edit' === tab.name ) {
                return this.getEditorWidget();
            }
        }

        doStuff() {
            // does some unrelated stuff...
        }

        getPlotWidget() {
            // returns a component...
        }

        getEditorWidget() {
            const { attributes } = this.props;
            const { script } = attributes;

            return el(
                Fragment,
                {},
                el(
                    'textarea',
                    {
                        name: 'textarea1',
                        value: script,
                    }
                ),
                el(
                    Button,
                    {
                        onClick: () => {
                            this.doStuff();
                        }
                    },
                    __( 'Run', 'my-textdomain' )
                )
            );
        }

        render() {
            return el(
                TabPanel,
                {
                    tabs: [
                        {
                            name: 'show',
                            title: __( 'Show', 'my-textdomain' ),
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'edit',
                            title: __( 'Edit', 'my-textdomain' ),
                        },
                    ],
                },
                ( tab ) => {
                    return this.renderTab( tab );
                }
            );
        }
    };
};
```

The tab panel is only created when the `render` function is called, so I guess one way to set the tab would be to persist it in the edit component's state, but this seems like it goes against the style of React/Gutenberg where objects are cheap to generate on-the-fly.

I could also store a property like `this.currentTab` which contains the current tab name, then in the tab panel use this property to determine the tab to show. This would require me to trigger a render from the button's `onClick` callback (how do you even do this?).

Comment: Rendering happens when the props change in React, you don't trigger a render as such, that's not how it works

Comment: Just so I understand it correct: You want to change between _show_ and _edit_ tabs? And this change should be triggered outside of `getEditComponent`? Where do you want to initate it?

Comment: @kero no, I'd like to have the tab component change tabs when a button is clicked elsewhere, when in the edit context. The problem is that there appears to be no way to set the tab component's current tab external to that tab, at least not via the `TabPanel` object itself. I think the solution will involve setting it via the DOM.

Comment: did you find asolution?

Comment: I ended up using a normal React tab panel that handles this stuff for me, not the Gutenberg one.

Comment: well, I will have to do the same now. shh

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party but I encountered this same problem and found this link, so my solution might still help someone else.

The `TabPanel` component has an `initialTabName` prop that can be used to set the tab. So create a state for this. However, changing this state does not re-render the component so we need to force this. This can be done by setting the `key` prop on `TabPanel` using some more state and updating it whenever the tab name changes.

In the end, my solution looked something like this:

```
function MyTabs() {
  const [tabState, setTabState] = useState({activeName, '', key: 0});
  function setActiveTab( activeName ) {
    setTabState(state => ({ activeName, key: state.key++ }))
  }

  return (
    <TabPanel
      initialTabName={ tabState.activeName }
      key={ tabState.key }
      ...
    >
      { tab => <Tab setActiveTab=setActiveTab ... /> }
    </TabPanel>
  )
}
```

The same can be achieved if the tab needs to be triggered from higher up in the hierarchy using a prop and useEffect. I haven't tested this but I expect it would look something like this:

```
function MyTabs({ tabName }) {
  const [tabsKey, setTabsKey] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => setTabState(key => key++), [tabName])

  return (
    <TabPanel
      initialTabName={ tabName }
      key={ tabsKey }
      ...
    >
      { tab => ... }
    </TabPanel>
  )
}
```